# How do i embed a imagine into my Python Program when turning it into a exectutable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, tkinter, exe

I have turned my program into a .exe file using auto-to-py-exe but the problem is that i always need to have the images included in the folder which my program lays in. Is there any way to include the images within the .exe file so its easier to distribute?

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()

try:
    img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('example.jpg'))
except:
    pass

canvas_picture = Canvas(root, height=90, width=90)
canvas_picture.place(x=315, y=5)
img_place = Label(canvas_picture, image=img1)
img_place.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I have been searching for a solution but havent found any. And since I'm extremely new to making python applications I dont have the slightest clue to what i should be doing.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What do think about the `^Additional Files` option [Screenshots](https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe#screenshots)

Comment: See [Is it possible to code images into a python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715244/is-it-possible-to-code-images-into-a-python-script) abd [JPEG Image Embedded in Python](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/216634/jpeg-image-embedded-in-python).